# Getting version of object after doing aws cp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm doing the following on a Versioned bucket:

```
aws cp file.zip s3://services/file.zip
```

I want to provide a report with the `version id`, but the only way I see to do it is the following:

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket services --prefix file
```

But it is a very expensive operation compared to a `cp`

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `aws 3 put-object` ([documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html)), it returns the `VersionId` immediately:

```
$ aws s3api put-object --bucket my-bucket --key foo.txt --body foo.txt

{
    "VersionId": "3MAIT3iXVh1WqhmaqB_l_pSnSy2G1H15", 
    "ETag": "\"0615be3428bfea43e8e1a1a4e991694b\""
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for John! Thank you